# Change subview on UIView ? [close]

Tags: iphone, uiview, nib

i have success show subview from another NIB, i have 2 button and 1 UIView on MainView, when i klick button 1 will show NIB1 on UIView, and then i klick button 2 will show NIB2 on UIView, but when i klick again button 1 UIView not show NIB1 again, but still NIB 2, this is my Code :

**Updated Solved**
On .h file

```
IBOutlet UIView *bottomView;
```

On .m file

```
-(IBAction) handleButton1{
    for (UIView *t in bottomView.subviews) {
        [t removeFromSuperview];
    }
    if (![nib1 isViewLoaded]) {
        nib1 = [[NIB1 alloc] initWithNibName:@"NIB1" bundle:nil];
    }
    [bottomView addSubview:nib1.view]; 
}

-(IBAction) handleButton2{
    for (UIView *t in bottomView.subviews) {
        [t removeFromSuperview];
    }
    if (![nib2 isViewLoaded]) {
        nib2 = [[NIB2 alloc] initWithNibName:@"NIB2" bundle:nil];     
    }
    [bottomView addSubview:nib2.view]; 


}
```

How i can refresh UIView with another NIB on my code ?
Thanks,
I have solve this case, i remove all subview on MainView from this `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3915729/refreshing-cell-content-after-deleting-cells` 
use :

```
for (UIView *t in bottomView.subviews) {
        [t removeFromSuperview];
    }
```

I hope this code help anyone :).

Answer (score 2):

You have to remove the first view view `[theViewYouDontWantToShow removeFromSuperview]`.

Or you can use `[bottomView bringSubviewToFront:nib1/2.view]`.

What was appending here is only that you added a view (this works), added the other view on top of the first one (this works too), but then you added the first one again. The view doesn't change since it's already there.

Comment: hi gcamp, thanks very much for your answer, i have test this `[bottomView bringSubviewToFront:nib1/2.view]` but overlap, nib2 show on bottom of nib1. and i test with `[theViewYouDontWantToShow removeFromSuperview]` but this is error "NIB1 may not respondes removeFromSuperview", any suggestion ?

Comment: You were actually trying to remove the viewController (NIB1), not the view itself. You should have put `[nib1.view removeFromSuperview]`... You can also accept or up vote the answer if it helped you.